# Why netcat listener inside of an Ubuntu docker container silently ignores specified port in favor of a random one?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

I would like to spawn a netcat listener on a given port inside of a docker container in order to manually debug incoming requests, but netcat's behavior inside docker seems different from what I used to observe in a non-dockerized setup. Taking vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 as an example:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 6010:6010 ubuntu:18.04

# inside container
apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat net-tools
nc -lk 0.0.0.0 6010 &

# then to verify what I am listening on
netstat -an|grep LISTEN

# example output:
# tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39331           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

No error of any kind, just a silent allocation of a different point. By the experience of non-dockerized listener spawning, I used to think that I will get either an error (such as port taken) or the requested port will be successfully allocated. What's going on here and how to force listening on the desired port?

Just to anticipate potential suggestions, as netcat's man says on `-p [port]` :

> It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.

Comment: check you are really installing the openbsd version and not the traditional version of netcat. Don't use the virtual package name netcat at all. (eg: `nc -l -p 6010` is valid syntax on traditional implementation). Anyway consider using socat instead as it's much more versatile.

Comment: Thank you @A.B. `socat` does the job indeed.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the BusyBox netcat version requires `-p` to specify the listening port, so the manual page you quote does not apply in this case. This is the correct command line for BusyBox netcat:

```bash
nc -l -p 6010      # IP can be left out if it is 0.0.0.0 (all IPs)
```

Here's the help page for nc in my version of alpine:

````
/ # nc -v
BusyBox v1.32.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [OPTIONS] HOST PORT  - connect
nc [OPTIONS] -l -p PORT [HOST] [PORT]  - listen

        -e PROG Run PROG after connect (must be last)
        -l      Listen mode, for inbound connects
        -lk     With -e, provides persistent server
        -p PORT Local port
        -s ADDR Local address
        -w SEC  Timeout for connects and final net reads
        -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
        -n      Don't do DNS resolution
        -u      UDP mode
        -v      Verbose
        -o FILE Hex dump traffic
        -z      Zero-I/O mode (scanning)```
````